# Hyper v not working. Hardware virtualization disabled at bios level

Tags: hyper-v, emulator, windows-phone-8

I have an Intel i5 460M processor and it does have **EPT**.
I tried the check slat tool and it says that hard virtualization is disabled at bios level but i enabled it already.

coreinfo gives me a strange error, says "error loading driver: the system cannot find the specified file."

The windows phones emulator requires me to have 8.1 pro on a 64 bit system with hyper v,
i fulfill the first requirement so it has to be some problem with the hyper v.

Comment: If its being reported as not being enabled then you need to figure out the reason thats the case.  Try disabling the feature, checking, then enabling the feature and checking, if you can enable it then your hardware is guaranteed to support it

Comment: it says hyper v disabled in firmware that is probably where the problem lies.

Comment: I thought you said you enabled it?

Comment: Have you tried what Ramhound suggested, ie. disable-check-enable?